# jQuery Datatables Lifecycle

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

Does anyone can explain `jQuery` datatables lifecycle?

I have a problem that on sme page I close datatable and open again (datatable reinitialization).
When open datatable second time filter stop working.

I'm gettting an error:

```
TypeError: oSettings is null
if ( !oSettings.oFeatures.bFilter )
```

I have no idea how to solve this problem.

UPDATE 1:

```
var oTable;
function datatable() {
oTable = jQuery('#tabela').dataTable({
    "oLanguage": {
        "sSearch": "Search:",
        "sInfoFiltered": '' 
    },
    "bDestroy": true,
    "bStateSave": false,
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "aLengthMenu": [[15, 25, 50, 100, -1], [15, 25, 50, 100, "all"]],
    "iDisplayLength": -1,
    "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
        $(nRow).addClass('gradeA');
        return nRow;
    }
}).columnFilter({
    aoColumns: [
        null,
        null,
        null,
        { type: "checkbox", values: ['BGD','BGDS','NS','NSS','LE','LES'] }
    ]
});
}

function datatable_delete() {
oTable.fnFilterClear(); 
oTable.fnDestroy();
}
```

Function datatable() I call when click on some link. Then, table opens on same page. On close button, table closes and datatable_delete() function is called. We are still on same page. When click on link to open table, mentioned problem occurs.

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function datatable_delete() {
  oTable.fnSettings().aoRowCallback = [];
  oTable.fnSettings().aoDrawCallback= [];
  oTable.fnDestroy();
}
```